Unable to make https call from one docker container to another in docker compose in .Net 8
On Windows, I created a .NET 8 project named ApiOne in Visual Studio, enabled Linux containers and HTTPS, and added container orchestration. I then added a second .NET 8 project, ApiTwo, to the same solution, also with Linux container support and orchestration. While I can make HTTP requests from ApiOne to ApiTwo, HTTPS requests between the two fail.
ApiOne Dockerfile:
# See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

# Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
# For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

# This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081


# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApiOne/ApiOne.csproj", "ApiOne/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ApiOne/ApiOne.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ApiOne"
RUN dotnet build "./ApiOne.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ApiOne.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiOne.dll"]

ApiOne launchSettings.json:
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5116"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7088;http://localhost:5116"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Container (Dockerfile)": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:22890",
      "sslPort": 44373
    }
  }
}


ApiOne and ApiTwo files are similar.

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  apione:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apione
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ApiOne\Dockerfile

  apitwo:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apitwo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ApiTwo\Dockerfile


docker-compose.override.yml:
services:
  apione:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
    ports:
      - "8080"
      - "8081"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
  apitwo:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
    ports:
      - "8080"
      - "8081"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro


This seems to be an issue regarding https certifcates. I went through the filesystem of both the containers to the directory C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Http and the .pfx files ApiOne.pfx and ApiTwo.pfx both were available in the mounted volume in both the containers' file systems. I am also able to make individual https calls when I use Postman to make https calls to ApiOne and ApiTwo. What am I missing?

What does fail mean, and why do you want HTTPS between containers? There's no intermediary that could snoop on the call, and the only allowed connections are those you specify explicitly. That's why containerized applications don't use HTTPS to talk to each other.

In any case, to use HTTPS you need to install a valid certificate on the server container. If you want to use a self-signed certificate for testing purposes, it needs to be trusted in both server and client containers. The code you posted doesn't show any attempt to add a certificate file, much less register it

The docs at Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS and Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker Compose over HTTPS explain how to create a certificate, mount it and use it, both with Docker and Docker Compose. In both cases, the certificate is stored in a folder that's mounted as a volume on the server container

The certificates automatically get created when I create the project using VS. I checked the container's file systems and the certificates ApiOne.pfx and ApiTwo.pfx are both the in mounted volumes. Both containers mount the same directory ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https in the host.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-certificate-management?view=vs-2022#certificates

I linked to the MS docs too. The link you posted don't say you should use ${APPDATA} - there's no such folder on Linux. %APPDATA%\ASP.NET\Https is the local Windows folder on the host where the certificate was stored. You can specify any other path you want. You need to map that folder to a valid container folder, eg /https and then use ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path to specify the container path to the certificate, eg ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/mycert.pfx
